# Why only one row is inserted into mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

Here is the full query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO db2.story (created, title, body) 
SELECT  
FROM_UNIXTIME(n.created),
n.title,  
b.body_value
FROM db1.node  n, db1.body_field b
WHERE n.nid= b.id  and n.type IN ('story');
```

The select part of of the query returns the full results but the whole query only inserts the first row.

What is wrong with this query and how to fix it?

UPDATE: Here is the structure of db2.story:

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title    | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| body     | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| teaser   | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| visits   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| slug     | varchar(100) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Get rid of the IGNORE and see the error that gets thrown.  Probably a key violation like dupolicate key.  You can always do a REPLACE INTO if performance isn't an issue and you want to update duplicates

Comment: When I get rid of IGNORE mysql complaints:  Duplicate entry '' for key 'slug', which is not surprising.

Comment: Is there a primary key on the table db2.story? Can you show us the output of `DESC db2.story`?

Comment: @AndrewJones Just updated the question with the table structure.

Comment: So you're passing in records, not all of which obey the constraints of the table you're inserting into? I think you should fix your select, not your insert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is the unique key that exists for the field `slug`. Because you aren't setting `slug` to anything in your insert statement, it is being set the same for every row inserted into the table. Since the value has to be unique, only the first insertion works. There are two possible ways to fix this issue:

1. Remove the unique constraint on `slug`
2. Add unique data to your insert statement for the `slug` field

Comment: If MySQL is not set to STRICT mode, the NOT NULL fields get set as an empty string ''. That's why there is a duplicate entry for '' on the `slug` field.

Comment: Right, after removing the uniqe constraint all rows are inserted. Many thanks.